# I can't read the other objects from file: java.io.streamcorruptedexception: invalid type code: ac

Tags: java, file-io, fileinputstream, dataoutputstream

I am trying to read all the saved objects from the file , but I am only able to read the first one and then an exception appears (`java.io.streamcorruptedexception: invalid type code: ac`)

Here is My Code :

```
public void loadfile()
{
try{
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("accounts.dat");
ObjectInputStream inputfile = new ObjectInputStream(file);
boolean endoffile=false;
while(!endoffile){
try{
   
accounts2.add((Account) inputfile.readObject());
}catch(EOFException e){
endoffile=true;
}
catch(Exception f){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, f.getMessage());
}
}
inputfile.close();
   
}catch(IOException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}

}
public void savefile(){
try{
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("accounts.dat",true);
ObjectOutputStream outputfile = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
for (int i =0 ; i < accounts.size();i++)
{


outputfile.writeObject(accounts.get(i));
}
    outputfile.close();
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Succesfully Registered");
 this.dispose();
    
    
    
}catch(IOException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to put the inputfile.readObject() value into a variable then you giving a new value to it in every iteration?

Comment: I'm appending the inputfile.readObject() into an arraylist (accounts2) to print them later

Comment: And you have multiple elements in the inputfile right?

Comment: Yes i have multiple objects in the file, the problem is when I'm reading the objects, i could only read the first object and after that an exception appears

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because there are 2 ObjectOutputStream, and (I'm not sure about this), it's possible that sometimes the first one is not/bad closed... Maybe try to use the same OOS?

Comment: I Believe that's not the case since i do not have 2 objectoutputstream